# BizTalk WCF LOB Adapter: Can I have customizable scheme name

Tags: c#, configuration, biztalk, machine.config, wcf-lob-adapter

WCF Lob adapter project item creates this file.
I want to keep the `SCHEME` and `SERVICENAMSPACE` values in a `machine.config` or `BTSNTSvc64.exe.config`

Is it possible? If not how can I keep it customizable setting.

```
using Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common;
/// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// Module      :  MyFirstInboundAdapter.cs
/// Description :  The main adapter class which inherits from Adapter
/// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace MyFirstInboundAdapterApp
{
    public class MyFirstInboundAdapter : Adapter
    {
        // Scheme associated with the adapter
        internal const string SCHEME = "TheDefaultScheme";
        // Namespace for the proxy that will be generated from the adapter schema
        internal const string SERVICENAMESPACE = "TheDefaultScheme://FirstInboundAdapterNamespace;
        // Initializes the AdapterEnvironmentSettings class
        static AdapterEnvironmentSettings environmentSettings = new AdapterEnvironmentSettings();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a question for BizTalk Server?

Comment: yes. Adapter development on BizTalk server

Comment: Ok, so you're writing a custom Receive Adapter then.  I would *not* use the WCF LOB SDK, instead I would use the regular BizTalk Adapter Framework, which is what the WCF stack is built on anyway.  WCF add's **a lot of unnecessary complication** for no benefit.